# Give an example of a graph  with ()=4 and ()=2. (Why was my answer incorrect?)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I got this wrong on an assignment I did. Why doesn't my graph satisfy the conditions?

[image: My answer]

Comment: You can color the vertices with one fewer color than you used.  Note that the colors of the "outer cycle" can be rotated, freeing up the blue color to use again for the "central" vertex.

Comment: Can you explain why $\chi(G) = 4$? What you have demonstrated is that $ \chi(G) \leq 4$.

Comment: @Hardmath That's it, you're 100% right thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has already been answered in the comments. The graph doesn’t fulfil the conditions because it can be coloured with $3$ colours, with the three vertices connected to the centre using only $2$ of the colours.